# Upgrading Cisco 500 series stackable switches in stacking mode

Tags: cisco, switching, stacking

My switch model is: SG500-28-K9-G5 to be precise.

I have four switches in stacking mode in my setup, and I want to upgrade them to a higher level firmware.

Is it recommended that I remove the switches from stacking and upgrade individual switches, or can I upgrade just the master and expect it to pass on the firmware change to others? After all, they work as one switch in stacking.

Also, if it is just the master I must upgrade, then do I have to change the boot code on others and just upgrade the firmware on the master? I got something like this from a website.

I have ended here after sifting through lot of manuals etc.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The 500_Series_Admin_Guide.pdf states the following:
There are two different ways to update images across the stack:
• Image can be updated prior to connecting a unit to the stack. This is the
recommended method.
• Upgrade device or stack. If the stack is updated, the slave units are
automatically updated. This is done as follows:

- Copy image from TFTP/SCP server to master, using the Upgrade/
  Backup Firmware/Language page.
- Change the active image, using the Active Image page.
- Reboot, using the Reboot page.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure towards the 500 series switches but in practice best that you install the new code on all the switches within the stack.

There are some nice commands to upgrade the images on the 2960, 3560, 3750, etc switches but not quite sure if the 500 series supports them.

If you have a cli on the switches, verify the bin image with the "verify /md5 flash:/"image-path.bin".

Next in config mode configure the stack to boot from the new bin image 
"#boot system flash:/"path-to-image.bin"

Very important is that you have access to the console port of the switch for emergency access. 
If the switches are at a remote site, perform a test upgrade in your lab/office to ensure the upgrade path is successful first.
It's quite a straightforward procedure performed hundreds of times by network admins bust always best to be prepared with eventualities.

The reload at a convenient time where the users will not be impacted as much :-)

Comment: Well I have figured out that to stack the switches they all need to be at the same FW initially. 

Once that is done they all become a logical switch and I get to manage them with one IP address

There's a master and backup so the question is whether I can upgrade just the master and the others get the FW from it. I use the GUI for upgrading, it's pretty straight forward.

Comment: That's excellent news :-) Also found the upgrade procedure by googling "500_Series_Admin_Guide.pdf". It should be quite straightforward as it appears you can use tftp, scp, etc.. to upgrade the master and the stack

Comment: i went through the guide already. I still have the doubt whether upgrading just the master will update all the switches too.

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade the Master.

[Software Auto Synchronization in Stack](http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/csbms/Sx500/administration_guide/Cisco_500Sx_v1_4_AG.pdf)

> All the units in the stack must run the same software version
>   (firmware and bootcode). Each unit in a stack automatically downloads
>   firmware and bootcode from the master unit if the firmware and/or boot
>   code that the unit and the master are running is different. The unit
>   automatically reboots itself to run the new version.